# Lead Acid Battery Voltage rises very quickly

Tags: batteries, analog, charger, charging, lead-acid

I am working on a charger for the first time.
m charging a lead-acid battery (6V) by supplying a voltage of 7-7.2V & 100mA. But the voltage rises from 6.10 to 6.30 in just 5-10 seconds.

What could be the possible reason?

Comment: The chemical processes in the battery change when you start charging, this can cause the voltage to change quickly. I don't think that is anything to worry about. As long as you don't exceed 6.8 by too much (7 V should still be OK) there is nothing to worry about.

Comment: But on internet i read every whwere that it normally takes about 7-8 hours to charge a lead-acid battery. But its happening very fast. in only 10-15 minutes. It reaches to 6.3 Volts in only 15 minutes. The voltage is 7-7.2 V and current flowing is 200-300mA

Comment: But 6.3 Volts does not mean the battery is charged. It will be fully charged when it has reached 6.8 Volts and then you should stop charging it. When it charges more quickly than you expect it to the battery might be worn out and needs to be replaced.

Answer (score 1):

A battery can be approximated as a voltage source in series with a resistor. If no current is flowing, you get the open load voltage of the cell across the terminals. If you charge the battery, the terminal voltage will instantly rise because of the resistive component of our model. The opposite happens when the battery is loaded: you see an instant voltage drop.

(Of course, in physical reality the voltage rises and drops aren't instant. More complex battery models take this into account.)

This is normal and expected behavior. The actual charging it discharging happens over a longer time, and is roughly equivalent to the model voltage source increasing in voltage. As the battery ages, the series resistance increases, meaning you can get less current into and out of the battery.